# Custom Sprintf (%s)

Tags: php, printf

Currently I'm using sprintf like this way:

```
$route = 'text.txt';
$route_r = file_get_contents($route);

sprintf($route_r, $custom_param1, $custom_param_2);
```

Inside text.txt we find this:

```
This is a test with param1 = %s and param 2 = %s
```

It really works okay, but I'd like something more "friendly", just like this:

```
This is a test with param1 = %param1 and param2 = %param2
```

They all are strings in this case. Is there any way to do this? Thanks

Comment: There is; it involves ditching `sprintf` for `str_replace` or `preg_replace_callback`. Has been answered before, not sure about where...

Answer (score 1):

`(s)printf()` allows only to specify the argument by it's index in argument list:

```
$route_r = "This is a test with param2 = %2s and param1 = %1s";
sprintf($route_r, $custom_param1, $custom_param_2);
```

This enables you to swap arguments or use them multiple times. Named params aren't supported.

It looks like you are searching for a template engine like [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net) or [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org) ?

Comment: Is there any other way without using sprintf?

Comment: You are searching for a template engine? Like [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net) or [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) ?